# Attach pdf to Woocommerce email generated by fpdf

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fpdf

I generate pdf by using fpf lib and trying hook in my pdf:

```js
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'aa_func_20151410051429', 10, 3);
function aa_func_20151410051429 ( $attachments, $status , $order) {
    $pdf_generic = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "pdf.php?order_id={$order->id}&attachment_on_fly=yes";
    $attachments[] = $pdf_generic;
    return $attachments;
}
```

For output i tryin different fpdf flags(or without flag):

```
$pdf->Output();
$pdf->Output("","D"); // download
$pdf->Output("","I"); // open in browser
$pdf->Output("","S"); // save in variable
$pdf->Output("","F"); // local save
```

but it didnt works for me.
What flag i miss or how can i solve this?

P.S all others pdf outputs works fine - eq manually create email and attach pdf, shown in browser, etc. Trouble only with attachmets to woo mails.

Comment: Can you generate the PDF and store it somewhere? And then you could attach it as a direct URL. WooCommerce emails are just wrappers for `wp_mail()` so see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142827/6477)

Comment: For each order? i dont think so...
if i has 1000-3000 orders? i must store all of this generated pdfs in host?

Comment: But if `wp_mail` requires an absolute URL, I'm guessing it won't support a file being generated on the fly.  You don't need to store them indefinitely. You could write a chron job to delete them every day... or even every hour. I think you  just need them long enough for WooCommerce to mail it.

Comment: yeah.. sounds like solution... thanks!

Comment: I even think you could delete the file after the mail is sent. ex: if `add_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock_notification', array( $this, 'no_stock' ) );` sends the no stock mail, you could, for example, run a function on the same `woocommerce_no_stock_notification` hook but with a later priority.